# Is a compact subset of the space of Radon measures Polish?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Denote by $M(\mathbb{R})$ the space of Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$ considered as the topological dual of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the locally convex inductive limit topology (as is done by Bourbaki). Equip $M(\mathbb{R})$ with the weak-* topology, i.e. $\mu_n \to \mu$ iff $\int f \, d\mu_n \to \int f \, d\mu$ for all $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$.

For a subset $H \subseteq M(\mathbb{R})$ the following are equivalent:
$H$ is relatively compact iff $H$ is bounded iff $H$ is equicontinuous.

It is known that $M(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable.
The subspace of positive measures is metrizable and moreover Polish.

I thought to have read somewhere that compact subsets of $M(\mathbb{R})$ are Polish, but I don't know whether this statement is really true. Does anyone know of a proof (maybe in a more general setup) or a counterexample?

Moreover, is the space $M(\mathbb{R})$ of all Radon measures in some way close to Polish,  e.g. Lusin or Souslin?

Comment: If $H \subseteq M(\mathbb{R})$ is weakly-* compact then it is weakly-* bounded and by the uniform boundedness principle it follows that $H$ is equicontinuous and thus norm-bounded. By Banach-Alaoglu, the norm-bounded subset $H$ of $M(\mathbb{R})$ is metrizable in the weak-* topology and thus $H$ is a compact metrizable space. Now a compact metrizable space is separable and thus Polish. The whole space $M(\mathbb{R})$ is not Polish but it is Lusin: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/220511/questions-on-topologies-on-space-of-radon-measures